# Qt GraphicsItem transformation affects all items in scene

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, embedded

I have this embedded Qt application that uses the QGraphics framework to display a web view.
The dimensions of the web view are 1280*720 pixels, and the QGraphicsView is set to render the scene at these coordinates (0,0, 1280x720).

I'm trying to add a loading indicator on the top right corner (at 1100,50), which is a simple PNG image that I rotate every now and then using a QTimeLine.

Code looks like this (I found the transformation trick on the internet):

```
// loading_indic initialization:
QGraphicsPixmapItem *loading_indic = 
             new QGraphicsPixmapItem( QPixmap("./resources/loading_64.png") );
loading_indic->setPos(QPoint(1100.0,50.0));

QTimeLine timeline = new QTimeLine(1000);
timeline->setFrameRange(0,steps);
connect(timeline, SIGNAL(valueChanged(qreal)), this, SLOT(updateStep(qreal)));
timeline->start();

// called at each step of a QTimeLine:
void updateStep(qreal step) {
    QTransform transformation = QTransform()
                // place coordinate system to the center of the image
                .translate(  width/2.0,  height/2.0) 
                // rotate the image in this new coordinate system
                .rotate(new_angle) 
                // replace the coordinate system to the original
                .translate( -width/2.0, -height/2.0);

    loading_indic->setTransform(transformation);
}
```

Now, my problem is that when doing this, it looks like the WebView is translated as well, resulting in everything being displayed in the center of the screen.

Result looks like this:

[image: problem]

The webview is supposed to fill the screen, and the loading indicator should be on top right...

My scene contains only two items:

```
Scene
  |
  \____ QGraphicsWebView
  \____ QGraphicsPixmapItem // loading indicator
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is loading_indic exactly? Where was it defined? I think, you need to provide more code.

Comment: You should show the code how you add loading_indic to a graphic scene.

Comment: I added some code to show you how I use the indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.. 
I don't know why, but it looks like adding this PNG item to the scene was screwing up with the scene's rectangle.

Doing this:

```
_scene.addItem(loading_indic);
loading_indic->setPos(1100.0, 50.0);
_scene.setSceneRect(0.0,0.0,1280.0,720.0); // resets the scene's rectangle ?!
loading_indic->startAnimation();
```

solved the problem. Now my items are correctly placed on screen.

If somebody has an explanation to this, I'll gladly accept his answer.

Comment: When you add item to a scene and sceneRect wasn't set before, it becames the bounding box of elements in the scene. And sceneRect propertie is used by QGraphicsView to show content of scene. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop